# dlsym - "Too many arguments to function" error

Tags: c, dynamic, shared-libraries, .so

I am doing a C exercise that involves loading a shared library dynamically. When I compile my test program using `gcc -o test2 test2.c -ldl` command, I get an error:

```
test2.c: In function ‘main’:
test2.c:27:5: error: too many arguments to function ‘test’
    (*test)(array, size);
```

This is the bit where I get the error:

```
void (*test)(void);    
test = dlsym(handle, "lib_fill_random");
(*test)(array, size);
```

`lib_fill_random` is declared with two arguments in both in .h and .c files as `void lib_fill_random(double *array, int size);`, and it works perfectly fine by itself.

What could be causing this issue?

Comment: The declaration `void (*test)(void)` means that the function takes no arguments.

Comment: @Barmar So it's supposed to be `void (*test)(double*, int);`? Sorry for such a ridiculous question, I just find dlsym a bit too confusing right now...

Comment: I guess you wrote that comment before seeing my answer.

Comment: dlsym has nothing to do with any of this, you can remove it from the code altogether and get the same error, so please remove it from the question too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function pointer declaration has to match the declaration of the actual function. So it should be:

```
void (*test)(double *, int);
```

Your declaration states that the function takes no arguments, so you get an error when you call it with arguments.